# Trying to implement breadth first search from text file in python

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

So I was able to implement breadth first search like this. But Now I am trying to implement breadth first search from a text file that looks like this.

Textfile:

```
1,1
1,1
4,1
4,5
5,1
```

This is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph:
def __init__(self): 
    self.graph = defaultdict(list) 
def addEdge(self,u,v):
    self.graph[u].append(v)
def BFS(self, s):
    visited = [False] * (max(self.graph) + 1)
    queue = []
    queue.append(s)
    visited[s] = True
    while queue:       
        s = queue.pop(0)
        print (s, end = " ")         
        for i in self.graph[s]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                queue.append(i)
                visited[i] = True
g = Graph()
g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(0, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(2, 0)
g.addEdge(2, 3)
g.addEdge(3, 3)
```

Output: 2 0 3 1

This is how I adjusted the text file, but i still cant figure out how to implement it:

```
data = open("ajd.txt", "r")
list_of_lists = []
for line in data.readlines():
    stripped_line = line.strip('\n')
    line_list = list(map(int, stripped_line.split(',')))

    list_of_lists.append(line_list)
data.close()
print(list_of_lists)
adjLists = list_of_lists
def convert(a):
    adjList = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[I])):
            if a[i][j]== 1:
                adjList[i].append(j)
    return adjList
```

Output:
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [4, 1], [4, 5], [5, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this is what you want, but I don't know if it's right.

There was no exact description of the `ajd.txt` file, so I put a value arbitrarily. Maybe `adj.txt` has an explanation of the `starting value`.
If you tell me that part, I can give you the exact details.

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    def BFS(self, s):
        visited = [False] * (max(self.graph) + 1)
        queue = []
        queue.append(s)
        visited[s] = True
        while queue:
            s = queue.pop(0)
            print(s, end=" ")
            for i in self.graph[s]:
                if visited[i] == False:
                    queue.append(i)
                    visited[i] = True


g = Graph()
g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(0, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(2, 0)
g.addEdge(2, 3)
g.addEdge(3, 3)

g.BFS(2)


def convert(a):
    adjList = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            if a[i][j] == 1:
                adjList[i].append(j)
    return adjList


print('')
data = open("ajd.txt", "r")
list_of_lists = []
for line in data.readlines():
    stripped_line = line.strip('\n')

    line_list = list(map(int, stripped_line.split(',')))

    list_of_lists.append(line_list)
    data.close()

print(list_of_lists)
adjLists = list_of_lists

new_g = Graph()

for line in list_of_lists:
    new_g.addEdge(line[0], line[1])

# I'm not sure the starting point, so i set it 3 randomly
new_g.BFS(3)
```